# JavaScript typeof, alert and apply

Tags: javascript

1) Why **in IE 8** typeof(window["alert"]) is "object" and not function?
2) How I can call apply method on "window.alert" ? I mean that what i'm trying to do is this:

```
function exec(method, param)
{
    //because of typeof(window["alert"]) == "object" the actual if looks like typeof(window[method]) == 'function' || method == 'alert'
    if(typeof(window[method]) == 'function')
    {
        window[method].apply(window, [param]);
    }
}

exec("alert","hello");
```

Comment: It's a [function for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/j4fGL/)

Comment: Hmmm, what browser do you use? I test it in IE8

Answer (score 1):

1. typeof window['alert'] is a "function"... (tested with FF)

try this code (typeof instead typeOf())

```
function exec(method, param)
{
    if(typeof window[method] == 'function')
    {
        window[method].apply(window, [param]);
    }
}

exec("alert","hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof window["alert"]` returns "object" in Internet Explorer versions below 9, but in Firefox it returns "function" . It's a known issue I guess. Below, here's an article that mentions it :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FOperators%2FSpecial_Operators%2Ftypeof_Operator

Answer (score 0):

1. typeof(window["alert"]) returns "function"
2. you have written **typeOf**. This works

   ```
   function exec(method, param)
   {
       //because of typeof(window["alert"]) == "object" the actual if looks like typeof(window[method]) == 'function' || method == 'alert'
       if(typeof(window[method]) == 'function')
       {
           window[method].apply(window, [param]);
       }
   }

   exec("alert","hello");
   ```